# How to find a devices(Hololens) latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I find the latitude and longitude of my Hololens device?

- I have found the solution for the same. I am sharing it here as it might be helpful some one else like me ;-)

0

I did lot of tests and found an solution using "http://ip-api.com/json" . I hope this may help you. To use this you need to have "SimpleJSON.cs.cs" under "Assets\Plugins" folder you can get simpleJSON.cs from this link http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON#Download

To use this just create a new C# script LocationFinder and paste the below code and attach it to a gameobject on the scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using SimpleJSON;

public class LocationFinder: MonoBehaviour
{
    string jsonData;

    // Use this for initialization
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting");
        // implememt WWW to get json data from any url 
        //http://ip-api.com/json
        string url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;

        // store text in www to json string
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            jsonData = www.text;
        }
        // use simpleJSON to get values stored in JSON data for different key value pair
        JSONNode jsonNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(jsonData);
        Debug.Log("Latitude " + jsonNode["lat"].ToString());
        Debug.Log("Longtitude " + jsonNode["lon"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: How to find? By looking. Where to find? I don't know. :D

Comment: A quick Google search brought this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinate.latitude - have you tried it?

Comment: I hope it works only with a device which has inbuilt GPS

Answer (score 0):

I did lot of tests and found an solution using "http://ip-api.com/json" . I hope this may help you. To use this you need to have "SimpleJSON.cs.cs" under  "Assets\Plugins" folder you can get simpleJSON.cs from this link http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON#Download

To use this just create a new C# script LocationFinder and paste the below code and attach it to a gameobject on the scene.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using SimpleJSON;

public class LocationFinder: MonoBehaviour
{
    string jsonData;

    // Use this for initialization
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Starting");
        // implememt WWW to get json data from any url 
        //http://ip-api.com/json
        string url = "http://ip-api.com/json";
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;

        // store text in www to json string
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
        {
            jsonData = www.text;
        }
        // use simpleJSON to get values stored in JSON data for different key value pair
        JSONNode jsonNode = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(jsonData);
        Debug.Log("Latitude " + jsonNode["lat"].ToString());
        Debug.Log("Longtitude " + jsonNode["lon"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I was really behind this problem and didn't find an proper solution and finally I found something so thought of sharing it with other so it might help some one.

Comment: This will not give you the Latitude and Logtitude of the device, this will give you Lat and Log of your ISP (Internet Service Provider) station

Comment: Did you just post an answer in the question field and then replied to your own "Answer" with the same answer?

Comment: @Saif - nope, he didn't - he first answered his own question, that seemed to be his goal all along since he had a hard time finding an answer and wanted to share his result that he had found - after the comment made by BugFinder he edited his question and also put the answer there, since BugFinder for what ever reason didn't think of this text as an answer - that's what happened